# How to limit Disk space for a user in zpanel?

Tags: centos, quota, zpanel

I have a package which has the quota of 2MB, however, I walk through FTP and it let me upload files larger than 2MB, while it should not!

How can I do to assign the disk QUOTA?

**I have it installed on CentOS 7.**